# Что значит транзакция в монопольном режиме?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
beginTransaction() //Begins a transaction in EXCLUSIVE mode.

endTransaction()  //End a transaction.
```

Что значит транзакция в `SQLiteDatabase` в **монопольном режиме** (EXCLUSIVE mode) и в каком случае применяются эти методы? Достаточно ли просто закрыть БД методом `db.close()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Транзакция - это (условно) работа с данными по принципу "всё или ничего". Если на каком-либо этапе выполнения транзакции происходит сбой, все предыдущие изменения должны быть отменены.

В SQLite транзакции имеют 3 режима блокировки. Из них EXCLUSIVE (монопольный) - самый высокий. В этом случае БД блокируется целиком и пока транзакция не завершится другие транзакции не могут даже прочитать данные из неё.

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](http://zametkinapolyah.ru/zametki-o-mysql/tema-15-tranzakcii-v-sql-na-primere-bazy-dannyx-sqlite-svojstva-acid-i-urovni-izolyacii-tranzakcij-v-sqlite3.html) и [здесь](http://www.fandroid.info/urok-38-tranzaktsii-v-sqlite-ispolzovanie-sqlitestatment/).

> Достаточно ли просто закрыть БД методом db.close()?

Нет. Транзакция (особенно монопольная) должна быть предварительно завершена при помощи метода `endTransaction`.